# How to import updated records from XML files into SQL Database?

Tags: sql, xml, ssis

So from last few weeks I was trying to design a SSIS package that would read some XML files that I have and move the data from it to the multiple tables I want.

These file contains different nodes like Individual (parent node) and Address, Alias, Articles (all child nodes of Individual) etc.

Data in those files look like this:

```
    <Individuals>
   <Individual>
       <UniqueID>1001</UniqueID>
       <Name>Ben</Name>
       <Soft_Delete>N</Soft_Delete>
       <Soft_Delete_Date>NULL</Soft_Delete_Date>
       </Individual>
       <Addresses>
            <Address>
          <Address_Line_1>House no 280</Address_Line_1>
          <Address_Line_2>NY</Address_Line_2>
             <Country>US</Country>
       <Soft_Delete>N</Soft_Delete>
       <Soft_Delete_Date>NULL</Soft_Delete_Date>
                </Address>
            <Address>
          <Address_Line_1>street 100</Address_Line_1>
          <Address_Line_2>California</Address_Line_2>
             <Country>US</Country>
       <Soft_Delete>N</Soft_Delete>
       <Soft_Delete_Date>NULL</Soft_Delete_Date>
                </Address>
               </Addresses>
                   </Individuals>
```

I was successful in designing it and now I have a different task.

The files I had were named like this: Individual_1.xml,Individual_2.xml,Individual_3.xml etc.

Now I have received some new files which are named like this:

Individual_UPDATE_20220716.xml,Individual_UPDATE_20220717.xml,Individual_UPDATE_20220718.xml,Individual_UPDATE_20220720.xml etc

Basically these files contains the updated information of previously inserted records

OR

There are totally new records

For example:

A record or a particular information like Address of an Individual was Soft Deleted.

Now I am wondering how would I design or modify my current SSIS package to update the data from these new files into my database?

Any guidance would be appreciated....

Thank you...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/942079/how-to-import-updated-records-from-xml-files-into.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have no problem reading the XML so I won't really talk about that. @Yitzack's comment to his prior answer is "a" way to do it. However, his answer assumes you can create staging tables. To do this entirely inside SSIS, the way to do it is as follows...

I would treat all the files the same (as long as they have the same data structure and it seems like the case.

1. Read the XML as a source.
2. Proceed to a lookup.
3. Set the lookup to ignore errors (this is handled in the next step)
4. Set your lookup to the destination table and lookup uniqueID and add to the data flow. Since you said ignore errors, SSIS will insert a null in that field if the lookup fails to find a match.
5. Condition Split based on the destination.UniqueID == null and call that output inserts and change the default to updates.
6. Add a SQL statement to update the existing record and map your row to it (this is somewhat slow and why the merge is better with large data sets).
7. Connect from Condition Split to update SQL statement and map appropriately.
8. Add an insert, connect the proper output from Conditional Split and map.

**Note:** It looks like you are processing from a file system, and it is likely that order is important. You may have to order you foreach loop. I will provide a simple example that you can modify.

1. Create a filesInOrder variable of type object.
2. Create a script task.
3. Add filesInOrder as a read/write variable
4. Enter script...

   ```
   var diFiles = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"path to your folder").GetFiles("*.xml");
   var files = diFiles.OrderBy(o => o.CreationTime).Select(s => s.FullName);
   Dts.Variables["filesInOrder"].Value = files.ToArray();
   ```
5. Make sure you add `Using System.Linq;` to your code.

Finally, use filesInOrder as your base to a foreach component based on an ADO enumerator (filesInOrder).